# Absolute value function homomorphism

Tags: functions, abstract-algebra

$\theta:\mathbb R^*\to \mathbb R ^+ $ defined by $\theta(a)=|a|$

I know this function is an homomorphism but how do you prove it?

Comment: It can't be since generally $\;|ab|\neq |a|+|b|\;$

Comment: @Timbuc it's a homomorphism if the operation is multiplication.

Comment: @MattS, I know...oh! So $\;\Bbb R^+\;$ shall represent the *positive reals under multiplication*, right?! I'm used to other notation and I thought that was all the reals under sum. Well, a lesson: define your notation.

Comment: What is $R^*$? Explain the notation.

Answer (score 1):

it is not a homomorphism under addition:

θ(3+(-2)) does not equal to θ(3)+θ(-2), θ(3+(-2))=θ(1)=1, θ(3)+θ(-2)=3+2=5

but it is a homomorphism under muliplication:

θ(ab) = θ(a)θ(b)

if a >= 0 and b >= 0, then |ab|=ab, and |a|=a, |b|=b, so |a||b|=ab=|ab|

if a<0 and b<0, then ab>0, so |ab|=ab, and |a|=-a, |b|=-b, so |a||b|=(-a)(-b)=ab=|ab|

if ab<0, then one of a and b is positive or zero, the other is negative, below we assume that a>=0 and b<0

if a>=0 and b<0, then ab<0, so |ab|=-ab, and |a|=a, |b|=-b, so |a||b|=a*(-b)=-ab=|ab|